# How to write dataframe results to teradata with session set commands enabled before writing using Spark Session

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, teradata, pyspark

My data is having Special characters(like Smiley Characters, some junk characters ). I want to insert the data as is into Terdata table. I can see that Hive stores data as with UTF-8 format. Where In teradata spark dataframe write is failing with error

> Error 6705 An illegally formed character string was encountered during translation

To fix the issue, I have followed the below process

1. Write custom Scala code using DriverManager and Connection createStatement.

> JDBC ConnectionString = jdbc:teradata://connection/DATABASE=dbname,CHARSET=UTF-8,COLUMN_NAME=ON,MAYBENULL=ON

2. Before writing the actual data , enabled SESSION commands -

> SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON

3. After session command execution is success then writing actual data to teradata table.

But I wanted to see is there any possible option to enable session level commands before writing dataframe data to teradata table.

Can I use session level set statements in dataframe option method ?
Like

> table_df.write.format("jdbc").option("url",jdbcurl").option("dbtable",tablename).option("dbname",dbname).option("username",user).option("password",password)

Please provide your thoughts on this. Thank you

Comment: Your session options aren't going to do you any good if the appropriate columns in the target table aren't defined with the appropriate character set. Why do you want to store what you describe as junk characters? I think in Pyspark you can encode your dataframe ansi and strip the junk out.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your response- My table columns are already in UNICODE CHARSET but still the job is failing, here junk characters like -  characters which are not in standard keyboard , for example - Register Symbol ® and single quote (´) which is different to normal quote ('). We need to store and display to end users as is without any Character skipping. I am able to achieve this by using custom Terdata insertion but not through Pyspark. I shouldn't skip any characters.

Comment: Unfortunately `write` method does not currently support `option("sessionInitStatement","...")` as `read` does. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28834

Comment: @Fred Thanks much for the information. Looks like its been open for a year. Hopefully issue will be closed soon. I will monitor this issue further and update here once I see any resolution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the Teradata JDBC Driver's `RUNSTARTUP=ON` connection parameter and specify the `SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON` command in the database user's `STARTUP` clause.

Please refer to the Teradata JDBC Driver User Guide for details, in the section titled **User STARTUP SQL Request**:

https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BGBHBDAB

Comment: Thanks Tom. Issue is solved by adding RUNSTARTUP=ON and added  session set commands to username. I could see results in Teradata tables as expected.